# ToString() method not working in Modle's Getter/Setter

Tags: c#, .net, tostring

I have a C# Model that contains a birthday. The birthday field takes the birthday from a separate API in the DateTime format. I've been trying to change this to a String instead, and I want to do it with Getters/Setters, if possible.

I get an error for ToString() when trying to do this. Error states "cannot convert from "string" to "System.IFormatProvider". I've tried lots of other variants of this and I just can not get something to work. I want to be able to achieve it via the Getters/Setters.

```
public class PersonLookUpModel 
   { 
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string? _dateOfBirthString;
        public string? DateOfBirthString { 
                         get => DateOfBirth; 
                          set => _dateOfBirthString = value.ToString("MMMM dd"); }
    }
```

Comment: `string.ToString()` won't support that format. Are you thinking of `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: Don't store dates as strings. Get rid of your _dateOfBirthString and DateOfBirthString members. Just use the DateOfBirth DateTime.

Comment: if `_dateOfBirthString` is public, then you may end with incorrect values in `public string? DateOfBirthString`. Nothing prevents coders to `myModel._dateOfBirthString = "hello!";` Your code would be more robust if you only can set the date of birth in a single way (ideally using the `DateOfBirth` property only).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
public class PersonLookupModel
{
   public DateTime DateOfBirth{get;set;}
   public string DOBString => DateOfBirth.ToString("MMM dd");
}
```

Comment: You could also keep the nullable types if you used the elvis (null conditional) operator.

Comment: Yes, this actually worked, too. I was definitely overcomplicating this in my head. Why don't I need getters/setters for the "DODString" field?

Comment: You are using a getter but don't need to set anything as you want to return the date as a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working:

```
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
public string _dobString;
public string DOBString { 
              get => _dobString = DateOfBirth?.ToString("MMMM dd"); 
              set => _dobString = value; }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).